# Android Socket Error when run on AVD

Tags: java, android, android-layout, sdk

I have a problem in the socket of the following code which made the program when I run it on AVD to stopped working (Unfortunately your -app- has stopped), I use Android 4.0 platform on Windows 7 ..
I tried to move the socket section to the button click, so when I click on the button the program stopped working, so here in the socket definition make the error. (Socket socket;)

```
public class ServerClient extends Activity {
// declaration of button, textView
private Button bt;
   private TextView tv;
  //port number
   private static final int REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT = 5000;
  //ip address
   private String serverIpAddress = "10.0.2.2";
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
      tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

         // on click on the button the socket will be created
      bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           Socket socket; //this line cause the app to stop working

         public void onClick(View v) {

          try {
             InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
             socket = new Socket(serverAddr, REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT);

          } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
          }
            try {
               EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
               String str = et.getText().toString();
               PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                     new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                     true);
               out.println(str);
               Log.d("Client", "Client sent message");

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
               tv.setText("Error1");
               e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               tv.setText("Error2");
               e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               tv.setText("Error3");
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I had the same problem (Windows 7, Android 4.03). I have solved the problem using android 2.33 (API level 10) and emulator with android 2.33 kernel.

Answer (score 2):

You Should forward the port from your PC to AVD by this command in `adb`:

```
adb forward tcp:YOUR_PORT_NUM tcp:YOUR_PORT_NUM
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the internet permission set in your AndroidManifest.xml?

You need this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Yes, I add this permission in AndroidManifest.xml
but the error still happened when the button is clicked ..

Comment: Then I suggest you use the LogCat tool in Eclipse to see what is happening. You will usually get an error message there along with a stack trace where you can see where things are going wrong.

Comment: When the LogCat is used the following error is happened...

03-07 20:52:00.056: E/AndroidRuntime(571): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.ServerClient/com.app.ServerClient.ServerClient}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: Ok, seems you are not allowed to make networking calls on the main thread on Android 3.0 and higher, so you must either start a new thread to make the request, or you can use something like AsyncTask (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I've been trying this code in earlier SDK (Android 2.3) but the issue happening again, so it does not depends on the Android Platform.   Is the AsyncTask could sends socket from android to PC?? If this possible is their any tutorial, plz ??